# Focussing on child dialog if clicked on other window (may be parent)

Tags: gtkmm

I have a main window and several other dialog windows which open from the main window on button clicks. When the user clicks on the main window while the child dialog window is opened, i want the focus to be set to child window. The user must first close the child and then click on main window. In Windows, it happens that it gives you sound as well as highlights the child window reminding the user that the child window is still opened and requires some action. How do i implement such functionality in gtkmm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are just describing a `modal` window.  If it fits your use case, there's a standard [Gtk::Dialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Dialog.html). If you want a completely custom `modal` window, any window can be made [modal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Window.html#a1f70b3c35e8c477ab3c1f9503a37a6a1).

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is exactly what i meant. But i didn't know the term 'modal'.

Comment: How should i bring this window into focus if the user tries to click outside this, on some other window?